# How to make this query to one?

Tags: mysql, sql

`select count(memberid) cnt from memberdata where MemberID;`

`select count(Deleted) UnUsable from memberdata where deleted = 1;`

`select count(Deleted) Usable from memberdata where deleted = 0;`

> Question How to make this query to one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like this

```
SELECT
  count(memberid) AS cnt,
  count(Deleted = 1) AS UnUsabl,
  count(Deleted = 0) AS Usable
FROM memberdata;
```

Answer (score 0):

As both query zo count the deletd are independent of the WHERE clause

make some suqueries of them

```
select 
count(memberid) cnt
,(SELECT count(deleted = 1) FROM memberdata) UnUsable
, (SELECT count(deleted = 0) FROM memberdata) Usable 
from memberdata where MemberID;
```